# Why do memory access times increase when far over CPU cache sizes

Tags: c++, performance, caching, memory, x86

In looking at performance issues involving large numbers of accesses outside of CPU cache sizes I made a test which "randomly" times memory accesses in increasing block sizes. I see the expected changes from L1,2,3 Cache block sizes but was surprised to see access time continue to decrease far beyond the cache capability.

For instance there was a halving in access times from thrashing a 256MB block to a 4GB block. From 50 read/writes per uS to 25 read/writes per uS. The decrease continues up to the system memory limit. I left 8GB (or 4GB) extra for other apps and OS.

The L3 cache is 8MB so I would have expected very little cache influence for the larger block sizes.

The algorithm uses primitive polynomials to "randomly" address each 64 bit word. This effectively accesses addresses in a fairly random way but assures that all addresses, except the 0 index, are accessed exactly once per pass. After a sufficient number of passes so that each one takes a second or so, the results are tabulated.

I'm at a loss to explain this continued access time decrease far beyond cache limits. Any explanations?

Here's the results from 3 different Windows 10 machines:

```
        | Memory block (bytes)
        |         | 64 bit words incremented per us
-- desktop I7 980 24GB --     -- Surface Book 16GB --      --HP Envy 8GB --
      128    544.80              128    948.43              128    774.22
      256    554.01              256   1034.15              256    715.50
      512    560.12              512    993.28              512    665.23
    1.02k    512.93            1.02k    944.24            1.02k    665.19
    2.05k    527.47            2.05k    947.09            2.05k    664.84
    4.10k    517.41            4.10k    931.48            4.10k    664.94
    8.19k    517.55            8.19k    939.61            8.19k    666.40
   16.38k    518.30           16.38k    941.18           16.38k    666.88
   32.77k    518.10           32.77k    938.77           32.77k    663.33
   65.54k    505.93           65.54k    889.42           65.54k    645.61
  131.07k    501.91          131.07k    855.01          131.07k    577.49
  262.14k    495.61          262.14k    882.75          262.14k    507.57
  524.29k    356.98          524.29k    774.23          524.29k    445.47
    1.05m    281.87            1.05m    695.35            1.05m    417.13
    2.10m    240.41            2.10m    650.26            2.10m    366.45
    4.19m    210.10            4.19m    229.06            4.19m    129.21
    8.39m    158.72            8.39m    114.95            8.39m     77.27
   16.78m     99.08           16.78m     84.95           16.78m     62.47
   33.55m     79.12           33.55m     60.14           33.55m     54.94
   67.11m     68.22           67.11m     34.56           67.11m     49.89
  134.22m     56.17          134.22m     22.52          134.22m     39.66
  268.44m     50.03          268.44m     23.81          268.44m     35.16
  536.87m     46.24          536.87m     39.66          536.87m     32.50
 1073.74m     43.29         1073.74m     30.33         1073.74m     25.28
 2147.48m     33.33         2147.48m     25.19         2147.48m     15.94
 4294.97m     24.85         4294.97m     10.83         4294.97m     13.18
 8589.93m     19.96         8589.93m      9.61
17179.87m     17.05
```

Here's the c++ code:

```
// Memory access times for randomly distributed read/writes

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

// primitive polynomials over gf(2^N)
// these form simple shift registers that cycle through all possible numbers in 2^N except for 0
const array<uint32_t, 28> gf = {
    0x13, 0x25, 0x67, 0xcb,                        0x1cf, 0x233, 0x64f, 0xbb7,
    0x130f, 0x357f, 0x4f9f, 0x9e47,                0x11b2b, 0x2df4f, 0x472f3, 0xdf6af,
    0x16b04f, 0x2e0fd5, 0x611fa7, 0xa81be1,        0x11f21c7, 0x202d219, 0x67833df, 0xbc08c6b,
    0x123b83c7, 0x2dbf7ea3, 0x6268545f, 0xe6fc6257
};

int main()
{
    typedef uint64_t TestType;
    printf("        | Memory block (bytes)\n        |         | %d bit words incremented per us\n", 8 * (int)sizeof(TestType));
    TestType *const memory = new TestType[0x8000'0000u];
    for (int N = 4; N < 32-0; N++)
    {
        const uint32_t gfx = gf[N - 4];
        const uint32_t seg_size = 1 << N;
        int repCount=1+static_cast<int>(gf[25]/(static_cast<float>(seg_size)));
        fill(&memory[1], &memory[seg_size], 0);
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point timerx(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
        for (int rep = 0; rep < repCount; rep++)
        {
            uint32_t start = 1;
            for (uint32_t i = 0; i < seg_size - 1; i++) { // cycles from 1 back to 1 includes all values except 0
                ++memory[start];
                start <<= 1;
                if (start & seg_size)
                    start ^= gfx;
            }
            if (start != 1)
            {
                cout << "ERROR\n";
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
        auto time_done = chrono::duration<double>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-timerx).count();
        auto x = find_if_not(&memory[1], &memory[seg_size], [repCount](auto v) {return v == static_cast<TestType>(repCount); });
        if (x != &memory[seg_size])
        {
            printf("Failed at memory offset %lld\n", x - &memory[0]);
            return -1;
        }
        long long int blksize = 4ll << N;
        if ((sizeof(TestType) << N) < 1000)
            printf("%9.0f    %6.2f\n", 1.0*(sizeof(TestType) << N), (seg_size - 1)*repCount / (time_done * 1'000'000));
        else if ((sizeof(TestType) << N) < 1000'000)
            printf("%8.2fk    %6.2f\n", .001*(sizeof(TestType) << N), (seg_size - 1)*repCount / (time_done * 1'000'000));
        else
            printf("%8.2fm    %6.2f\n", .000001*((long long int)sizeof(TestType) << N), (seg_size - 1.)*repCount /(time_done * 1'000'000));
    }
    cout << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you disabled swap?  I'd expect swappimg virtual memory in/out to dominate as you approach physical memory size.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  The runs leave between 4 and 8GB of ram. No swapping occurred in the posted results. I also fill the test area with zeros before starting the timing.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  I just tried it with `VirtualLock()` . No difference.

Comment: You have zero filled the memory you're accessing, the CPU is aware of this. Pre-initialise the ram with random values before running your timing test.

Comment: I think memory fragmentation plays the leading role here, you could verify that with GetProcessMemoryInfo,

Comment: @Geoffrey: That's of course not the case. The CPU does know that you have filled _some_ memory with zeroes; that knowledge is in the cache. But the question already addresses that. There's no component in the CPU that has enough storage to know that you've zeroed all of memory. And while the OS probably holds a list of "zeroed pages", that is a list of pages that **it** zeroed. Your own pages do not count.

Comment: The issue on my machine is more subtle: 128MiB -> 16GiB is: 119->84, so it is 1.4x. In your case, it is 56->17, which is 3.3x.

Comment: @geza: do you have a Skylake?  It has two HW page walkers that can work in parallel to give it 2x the TLB miss throughput vs. Broadwell and earlier Intel.  The OP is testing on an i7-980, which is a Nehalem (very old, significantly smaller out-of-order window, and slower DRAM bandwidth than a modern desktop.  DRAM latency might not be too dissimilar, though.  But differences in caching of higher levels of the page table is probably significant.)  And of course if you're using Linux, transparent hugepages might have helped...  IDK what Windows does.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I have a 5820k (Haswell), and I've tried this on Linux. I didn't know about transparent hugepages feature. And indeed, you are right. I've disabled it, and now the difference is more significant: 65->17, it is a 3.8x difference, worse than OP's one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The throughput continues to decrease because the page walking time increases per element, as the total number of elements increase. That is, the amount of time spent on filling the TLB does not scale with the number of elements. You can observe this using the `DTLB_LOAD_MISSES.WALK_DURATION` performance counter and other counters related to the page walking hardware. This is expected because when the number of 4K pages accessed increase, the depth and the breadth of the page table that map the working set also gets larger, and hence it is less likely to find the required page table entries at memory levels closer to the core.

Comment: Interesting! This makes sense. It seems windows uses small page sizes for mapping ram by default. Apparently larger page sizes can be configured but at some decrease in security. That might speed things up in the larger block sizes since it's pretty clear the ram address lookup tables are getting pushed out of cache.

Comment: @doug Using large pages (2MB or 1GB) will probably improve performance. If you have the time to run the experiments, I'm interested in seeing the numbers when using 2MB and 1GB pages, to see whether throughput will still decrease and by how much. In that case, there can be other factors. This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/large-page-support) might be helpful.

Comment: I've checked it on Linux, and found no speed difference. I've allocated memory with: `TestType *const memory = reinterpret_cast<TestType*>(mmap(0, 0x4000'0000*sizeof(TestType), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS/*|MAP_HUGETLB|(21 << MAP_HUGE_SHIFT)*/, -1, 0));` (uncomment the extra `MAP_*` flags to switch between huge and normal page sizes)

Comment: @geza What CPU are you using? Try also with 1GB pages.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I turned out (check out Peter's comment under the question), that Linux has transparent hugepages feature, that's why I don't see any difference.